# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Widget_Custom_HTML' not found

Tags: wordpress

Sorry if I don't write it right(it is my 1st post here).

I was editing a site adding pages and posts and after I refresh I see this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Widget_Custom_HTML' not found
> in
> /home/u430904391/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php:106
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/u430904391/public_html/wp-includes/widgets.php(113):
> WP_Widget_Factory->register('WP_Widget_Custo...') #1
> /home/u430904391/public_html/wp-includes/widgets.php(1477):
> register_widget('WP_Widget_Custo...') #2
> /home/u430904391/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298):
> wp_widgets_init('') #3
> /home/u430904391/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(323):
> WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #4
> /home/u430904391/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(453):
> WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #5
> /home/u430904391/public_html/wp-settings.php(448): do_action('init')
>
> ## 6 /home/u430904391/public_html/wp-config.php(92): require_once('/home/u43090439...') #7
>
> /home/u430904391/public_html/wp-load.php(37):
> require_once('/home/u43090439...') #8
> /home/u430904391/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(13):
> require_once('/home/u43090439...') #9
> /home/u430904391/public_html/index.php(17): require in
> /home/u430904391/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php
> on line 106

Comment: Try to narrow the issue down a bit.  Can you show us what you think actually caused the error?

Comment: @Tsakman Do you solve the question? I have the same problem